# Web Crawling a Dynamic Form

Tags: c#, javascript, html, web, web-crawler

I'm currently trying to spider a page that seems to have a dynamic form.  First let me explain the form.  The form has 3 radio dials above the search bar that has the first dial selected upon loading.  I need the second dial selected.  After selecting the second dial from the 3 dials I need to fill out the search bar which is actually a drop down, 
in the inspector looks like 
" id="*********" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" size="60" name="*********" style="font-size:20px;width:90%;;" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">>"

Originally the html behind the search/submit button looks like
a id="submit_button" style="display:none;" href="#">

After selecting from the dropdown menu the html behind the search/submit button looks something like 
a id="submit_button" style="" href="report.php?******=Mzg4MDU4NQ%3D%3D&******=MjQ1NDM2NQ%3D%3D">

Obviously the stars are there to keep the page anonymous.  I'm using a Web client to spider this page.

All I need to grab from this page is the new href link which is dynamically changed after a item is selected from the drop down.  I need to simulate this in C# and parse the href link.  Frankly, I don't know where to even begin.

I have tried using a nameValueCollection to fill in this form using UploadValuesAsync() but no avail.

Comment: have you tried selenium ?

Comment: You could maybe use [WatiN](http://watin.org/) it is mostly used for tests and it might be an heavy solution in you case but WatIn can emulate a browser and it will take care of the page construction for you and have a nice set of crowling functions.